# Move Marker upward

Tags: android

I am using a layout over google map .it becomes visible on clicking a marker.
I want to make the position of marker above the layout so that marker is visible to user.currently it is below the layout.
[image]

Comment: post some code and snapshot...

Comment: I used normal animate function map.animate(latlng),but the marker is animate towards center of the map.I need it to animate to top of the layout.